# Terminator command history

Tags: command-line, terminator

I have been looking into this - but I can't get previous entered commands in Terminator (multi-terminal). I have looked into the Preference but I don't see how it is done.

I know this is not really Ubuntu question, but I am sure many of you have used Terminator.

Does anyone know how to get the previous entered commands?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you use a shell that supports arrow up/down like bash.

Comment: yes. i was. i reinstalled terminator. and now it works. thanks to all of you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try typing:

```
history
```

in your terminal.

Or you could search it with CTRL-r.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: Shift-Ctrl-f seems to search the transcript from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Also You can just use the up-arrow to see the previously used commands.

Answer (score -1):

Try with [this](http://urosv.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/dopolnevanje-ukazov-iz-zgodovine-auto-complete/):

1. edit /etc/inputrc

*`sudo vim /etc/inputrc`*

1. uncomment or add this two line

   "\e[5~": history-search-backward

   "\e[6~": history-search-forward
2. logout/login

---

then try to write some command listed in history...

like...

```
ls -lah
```

write

```
ls
```

and press

**page up**

If you did everything right it should auto-complete your command :)